# access data from matrix with contiguous data

Tags: c, matrix

I write a function which create a matrix with a contiguous data but I don't understand how I can access to these one. the function is:

```
int create_matrix(struct matrix *a, size_t m, size_t n)
{
   a->m=m; 
   a->n=n;

   a->data = malloc(a->n*sizeof(double*));
   a->data[0] = malloc((a->n*mat_somma->m)*sizeof(double));

   for (size_t r=1;r<mat_somma->N;++r)
   {
      a->data[r]=a->data[0] + a->m*r;        
   }

   return 1;
}
```

EDIT:
this is an example of contiguous data in matrix but accessing with 
double indices. if found this here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/

I have an error in a->data[0]=malloc.....: impossible to convert from void to double(on visual studio).

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: You don't seem to be creating a "matrix with contiguous data" in your code

Comment: You have created `a->data` as type `double **` (a *pointer-to-pointer-to-double* (`a->n` pointers to be exact)). It is not contiguous. Each of the pointers created by `a->data = malloc(a->n*sizeof(double*));` will point to a separate address in memory.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix with contiguous data would have for e.g. all rows in a single row (row major). So

1. `a->data` would be of type `double*`.
2. You would allocate like : `a->data = malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));`
3. You would access element at `row` and `col` as : `a->data[row*n + col]`

Assuming `m` is the number of rows and `n` the number of columns